# Как можно получить чистыю ссылку без html кода

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://prnt.sc/saawq4'
HEADERS = {
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0'
}
responese = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responese.content,'html.parser')
items = soup.findAll('div',class_ = 'image-constrain js-image-wrap')
copms = []

for item in items:
    comps = []
    comps.append({
        'title':item.find(class_ = 'no-click screenshot-image'.format(soup.img,soup.img.text))
        })
    for comp in comps:
        print(comp["title"])
```

Как можно получить эту https://image.prntscr.com/image/NR-6f8psQUWSechxExKg7g.png ссылку без html кода

```
<img alt="Lightshot screenshot" class="no-click screenshot-image" crossorigin="anonymous" id="screenshot-image" image-id="saawq4" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NR-6f8psQUWSechxExKg7g.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто необходимо немного дописать в последнем цикле

```
for comp in comps:
        a = comp["title"]
        print(a['src'])
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное